# FSLeyes not opening, "AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute '__version__'"

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to install FSLeyes. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I tried using the following the command:
pip install --only-binary wxpython -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk2/ubuntu-16.04/ wxpython
pip install fsleyes[extras]

It is giving the following error:
AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute '**version**'

P.S. - I have installed FSL already but still not able to open FSLeyes from there.